# Store count as variable and use it for calculations in PySpark

Tags: sql, pandas, variables, filter, pyspark

I have dataframe df1:

```
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+
|   sid|acc_term_id|first_name| last_name|major|
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+
|106454|      2014B|     Doris|  Marshall|  BIO|
|106685|      2015A|      Sara|Richardson|  CHM|
|106971|      2015B|      Rose|    Butler|  CHM|
|107298|      2015B|     Kayla|    Barnes|  CSC|
|107555|      2016A|   Carolyn|      Ford|  PHY|
|107624|      2016B|     Marie|      Webb|  BIO|
```

I want to store the count of sid from this dataframe

```
c_value = current.agg({"sid": "count"}).collect()[0][0]
```

and use it for creating a **prop** column as shown in code below:

```
    c_value = current.agg({"sid": "count"}).collect()[0][0]
stud_major = (
    current
    .groupBy('major')
    .agg(
    expr('COUNT(*) AS n_students')
    
    )
    .select('major', 'n_students', expr('ROUND(n_students/c_value, 4) AS prop'),
    )
)

stud_major.show(16)
```

When I run the code I get error:

```
cannot resolve '`c_value`' given input columns: [major, n_students]; line 1 pos 17;
```

If I put numeric value 2055 instead of c_value everything ok like below.

+

```
-----+----------+------+
|major|n_students|  prop|
+-----+----------+------+
|  MTH|       320|0.1557|
|  CHM|       405|0.1971|
|  CSC|       508|0.2472|
|  BIO|       615|0.2993|
|  PHY|       207|0.1007|
+-----+----------+------+
```

Probably there are other ways to calculate but I need by storing **count** as **variable**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to give a sample of expected output?

Comment: @wwnde yes edited question

Comment: Pandas `df.groupby("major")['sid'].agg(n_students=(lambda x: x.count()), pop=(lambda x: x.count()/df.agg({'sid':'count'})))` your numbers werent representative

Comment: @wwnde I need to store count as variable

Comment: Ok, is the answer  what you are after?

Comment: @wwnde Not working I get error 'GroupedData' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233207/discussion-between-wwnde-and-user1997567).

Comment: See my edits. You have to f string the  variable

Answer (score 1):

In jupyter Use pandas agg

```
j=df.agg({'sid':'count'})
df.groupby("major")['sid'].agg(n_students=(lambda x: x.count()), prop=(lambda x: x.count()/j))



    major  n_students  prop
0   BIO           2  0.333333
1   CHM           2  0.333333
2   CSC           1  0.166667
3   PHY           1  0.166667
```

and pyspark

```
  from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.groupby('major').agg(count('sid').alias('n_students')).withColumn('prop', round((col('n_students')/c_value),2)).show()
```

Alternatively You could

```
c_value = df.agg({"sid": "count"}).collect()[0][0]




df.groupBy('major').agg(expr('COUNT(*) AS n_students')).selectExpr('major',"n_students", f"ROUND(n_students/{c_value},2) AS prop").show()

+-----+----------+----+
|major|n_students|prop|
+-----+----------+----+
|  BIO|         2|0.33|
|  CHM|         2|0.33|
|  CSC|         1|0.17|
|  PHY|         1|0.17|
+-----+----------+----+
```